# Mapbox marker property update: Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox

Working with the Mapbox JS API and am wondering why Marker properties cached in variables don't update, but their non-cached counterparts do.

For example, this will update the marker's custom `state` property as expected (defined in a geoJSON object elsewhere):

```
map.markerLayer.on('click',function(e) {
  var marker = e.layer;
  var properties = marker.feature.properties;
  var id = properties.id;
  var state = properties.state;

  if (state === 'active') {
    panels.hidePanel(id, function(){
      e.layer.feature.properties['state'] = 'inactive';
    });
  } else {
    panels.showPanel(id, function(){
      e.layer.feature.properties['state'] = 'active';
    });
  }
});
```

But this does not:

```
map.markerLayer.on('click',function(e) {
  var marker = e.layer;
  var properties = marker.feature.properties;
  var id = properties.id;
  var state = properties['panel-state'];

  if (state === 'active') {
    panels.hidePanel(id, function(){
      state = 'inactive';
    });
  } else {
    panels.showPanel(id, function(){
      state = 'active';
    });
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me understand what's happening with the latter?  Why can't I cache the references in variables rather than updating `e.layer.feature.properties['state']` every time?

Comment: sorry i can't help, but thanks for introducing me to mapbox - looks like cool stuff

Comment: It is indeed awesome, in the full sense.  Glad to have turned you on to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a basic Javascript question: objects hold references to variables. If you change these references *in the object* then they're updated in place. If you pull out the variables themselves and change them, they aren't. Example: http://mistakes.io/#6220549

Comment: Thank you! It's shocking/shameful I've not run into this sooner. Time to dust off The Good Parts text that I've been putting off forever :)